# Como eu salvo a opção escolhida pelo usuário html em cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background

Eu tenho um sistema de mudança de plano de fundo por Javascript no meu site, e quero que quando o usuário escolher o fundo que deseja, o fundo que ele escolheu se mantenha quando ele acessar o site novamente.

JavaScript

```
function mudar9(){ document.body.background = "fundos/9.png"; }
```

HTML

```
<a href="javascript mudar9();"></a>
```

Comment: Como quer guardar essa infomação? Numa base de dados, Cookie ou ficheiro? E que linguagem têm no lado do servidor?

Comment: Cookie. Assim como no Delta-Search: http://www.delta-search.com

Comment: Ok, pode colocar o código que já tem? assim podemos ser mais claros na resposta.

Comment: function mudar9(){
document.body.background = "fundos/9.png";
}
<a href="javascript mudar9();"></a>

Comment: Desculpe a demora.

Comment: Gustavo, vou fechar esta como duplicada da nova pergunta que fêz. Coloquei esta info lá e acrescentei outras opções á resposta. Se quiser pode marcar a minha pergunta como aceite uma vez que a pergunta é específica sobre Cookie.

Answer (score 7):

Sugiro usar o código que está na página da MDN para criar e ler cookies. (Coloco tambem no fundo da resposta.)

E nesse caso a sintaxe será:

> *docCookies.setItem(name, value[, end[, path[, domain[, secure]]]])* - criar o cookie
>   *docCookies.getItem(name)* - ler o cookie
>   *docCookies.removeItem(name[, path[, domain]])* - remover o cookie

Usando esse código como suporte, depois pode usar assim:

```
var fundo = docCookies.getItem('corDeFundo') || "#fff";
$('body').css('background-color', fundo);
$('button').on('click', function(){
    fundo = $(this).data('value');
    docCookies.setItem('corDeFundo', fundo);
    $('body').css('background-color', fundo);
});
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/wpnk5ep8/

(Teste fazer refresh ao exemplo depois de ter mudado a cor e vai ver que o Cookie guarda a unformaçõ.

---

### Código na [página da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie):

```
var docCookies = {
  getItem: function (sKey) {
    if (!sKey) { return null; }
    return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
  },
  setItem: function (sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure) {
    if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(sKey)) { return false; }
    var sExpires = "";
    if (vEnd) {
      switch (vEnd.constructor) {
        case Number:
          sExpires = vEnd === Infinity ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case String:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case Date:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toUTCString();
          break;
      }
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
    return true;
  },
  removeItem: function (sKey, sPath, sDomain) {
    if (!this.hasItem(sKey)) { return false; }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");
    return true;
  },
  hasItem: function (sKey) {
    if (!sKey) { return false; }
    return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
  },
  keys: function () {
    var aKeys = document.cookie.replace(/((?:^|\s*;)[^\=]+)(?=;|$)|^\s*|\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?(?:\1|$)/g, "").split(/\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?;\s*/);
    for (var nLen = aKeys.length, nIdx = 0; nIdx < nLen; nIdx++) { aKeys[nIdx] = decodeURIComponent(aKeys[nIdx]); }
    return aKeys;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar os cookies, como já foi apresentado na outra resposta, ou então usar o local storage, que é bem simples e não carrega suas requisições com dados desnecessários.

[Aqui](http://zenorocha.com/html5-local-storage/) um post excelente sobre o assunto.