# Como persistir uma informação após recarregar a página? (ex: um background escolhido)

Tags: javascript

Tenho um script de troca de background do site:

```
function bac(){
    document.body.background = "img/1.png";
}

<a href="#" onclick="javascript: bac();">
```

O usuário pode escolher qual a imagem do plano de fundo do site, mas quando a página recarrega, o fundo volta a ser branco. Tem como salvar a opção que o usuário escolheu, até mesmo se ele reiniciar o pc?

Comment: Você pode usar cookies para persistir a url da imagem do background e quando recarregar a página, você verifica se existe valor no cookie e atribui ao background novamente. Segue esse [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) de como trabalhar com cookies em javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para guardar informação de um utilizador tem 3 opções:

### Guardar na base de dados

Esse caso precisa de autentificação/login. Aí quando o utilizador clickar tem de enviar um AJAX para o servidor para poder guardar os dados e a referência do nome do utilizador.

<sub>Não creio que seja o que pretende mas tinha de o referir.</sub>

### Guardar no Storage do HTML5

A API do HTML5 têm duas opções, dois tipos: **sessionStorage** e **localStorage**.

A *sessionStorage* é só para a sessão e perde-se quando a janela fechar. O que quer usar é o *localStorage* que permanece no computador mesmo que este seja reiniciado.

Esta API tem os métodos:

- `.setItem(<nome>, <dados>)` Para escrever um novo registo
- `.getItem(<nome>)` Para lêr um registo gravado

Um exemplo para o seu caso seria:

```
function bac(imagem) {
    imagem = imagem || "img/1.png";
    localStorage.setItem("corDeFundo", imagem);
    mudarFundo(imagem);
}

function mudarFundo(url) {
    document.body.background = "url(" + url + ");";
}
if (localStorage.background) mudarFundo(localStorage.getItem("corDeFundo"));
```

### Guardar em Cookie

Já tinha dado esta resposta [noutra pergunta sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32478/129).

Sugiro usar o código que está na página da MDN para criar e ler cookies. (Coloco tambem no fundo da resposta.)

E nesse caso a sintaxe será:

> *docCookies.setItem(name, value[, end[, path[, domain[, secure]]]])* - criar o cookie
>   *docCookies.getItem(name)* - ler o cookie
>   *docCookies.removeItem(name[, path[, domain]])* - remover o cookie

Usando esse código como suporte, depois pode usar assim:

```
var fundo = docCookies.getItem('corDeFundo') || "#fff";
$('body').css('background-color', fundo);
$('button').on('click', function(){
    fundo = $(this).data('value');
    docCookies.setItem('corDeFundo', fundo);
    $('body').css('background-color', fundo);
});
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/wpnk5ep8/

(Teste fazer refresh ao exemplo depois de ter mudado a cor e vai ver que o Cookie guarda a unformaçõ.

---

### Código na [página da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie):

```
var docCookies = {
  getItem: function (sKey) {
    if (!sKey) { return null; }
    return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
  },
  setItem: function (sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure) {
    if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(sKey)) { return false; }
    var sExpires = "";
    if (vEnd) {
      switch (vEnd.constructor) {
        case Number:
          sExpires = vEnd === Infinity ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case String:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case Date:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toUTCString();
          break;
      }
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
    return true;
  },
  removeItem: function (sKey, sPath, sDomain) {
    if (!this.hasItem(sKey)) { return false; }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");
    return true;
  },
  hasItem: function (sKey) {
    if (!sKey) { return false; }
    return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
  },
  keys: function () {
    var aKeys = document.cookie.replace(/((?:^|\s*;)[^\=]+)(?=;|$)|^\s*|\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?(?:\1|$)/g, "").split(/\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?;\s*/);
    for (var nLen = aKeys.length, nIdx = 0; nIdx < nLen; nIdx++) { aKeys[nIdx] = decodeURIComponent(aKeys[nIdx]); }
    return aKeys;
  }
};
```

Comment: Tem alguns que deram respostas, vc deu uma aula e dicas valiosas para que o projeto seja cross-browser, infelizmente as vezes usuários só querem o simples e não se aprofundam em dicas valiosas como as suas. Parabéns +1

Answer (score 3):

Há a opção de utilizar Local Storage presente no HTML5.

**Exemplo:**

```
// Sempre que carregar a página verifica se existe um background pré-definido
if (localStorage.background) 
    document.body.background = localStorage.getItem("background");

// Guarda o background escolhido
function bac(){
    localStorage.setItem("background", "img/1.png");
    document.body.background = "img/1.png";
}
```

Comment: Funcionou mesmo! Muito obrigado! Vlw!